# Cannot delete or update a parent row

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try and delete a movie from my database I get a the above error. I believe I have some how made the rated table have precedence over the films table. 
How do I make the film table have precedence of the rated table

```
DELETE FROM  `film`.`films` WHERE  `films`.`movie_id` =16

--
-- Table structure for table `films`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `films` (
  `movie_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `actor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rated` (
  `rated_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rated_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rated_id`),
  KEY `movie_id` (`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


ALTER TABLE `rated`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `rated_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `films` (`movie_id`);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign key you have defined on `movie_id` by default restricts the deletion: with the current schema **you cannot delete a film as long as it has ratings.**

You can automatically delete the ratings when you delete the film using *cascading delete*. Whether this is the best option for your application is for you to decide...

```
ALTER TABLE `rated` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) 
          REFERENCES `films` (`movie_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: How would I alter the table so that I can delete a film along with it's ratings ?

Comment: You have to change the foreign key definition - see the update.

Comment: Yeah that worked brilliantly. I'm new to MySQL I assumed that tables that are connected by a foreign key would automatically delete the corresponding data.

Comment: The default in MySQL is "on delete restrict". I guess it's that way because many people just don't like cascading delete. If you are not careful you may end up deleting a lot more than you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a foreign key constraint you have to first delete any child records before you can delete the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting everything from Rated table first, then deleting from films table.

```
DELETE FROM Rated
WHERE Movie_ID = 16

DELETE FROM Films
WHERE Movie_ID = 16
```

Comment: Yeah it works fine when deleted that way. How do I delete from films then it deletes it's foreign key and its values ? if this function is possible.